# Small door on window screen

Tags: windows

Anyone know what this small hinged opening on the kitchen window screen would be for?[image][image]

Comment: Maybe a bird feeder or window box for flowers ?

Answer (score 3):

It’s called a “wicket”. It’s used when the window screen is on the inside and the window has an operator (crank, etc.) that opens the window “out”.